# MySQL UPDATE with LEFT JOINS

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query:

```
UPDATE 
    `product_pricing` 

SET `formula_id`= '2'

WHERE 1
```

---

```
SELECT

product_pricing.id,
product_pricing.formula_id,
product_pricing.vat_calculated,

products_ids.id,
products_ids.link_id,

product_attributes.fty_id,
product_attributes.size_id,

product_sizes.size_id,
product_sizes.wheel

FROM product_pricing 

LEFT JOIN products_ids ON product_pricing.id = products_ids.id
LEFT JOIN product_attributes ON products_ids.link_id = product_attributes.fty_id
LEFT JOIN product_sizes ON product_attributes.size_id = product_sizes.size_id

WHERE

product_sizes.wheel = '13'
```

How would I incorporate the SELECT query with the update query?

I need to only update products that have `product_sizes.wheel = '13'` but to get this information, I need a few left joins.

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am trying to update only the product that have `product_sizes.wheel = '13'`. To know which products do, I need a few `LEFT OUTER JOINS`. Now sure how to combine the two.

Comment: @Born . . . You second query has no table alias called `product_sizes` making the question even more inscrutable.

Comment: @GordonLinoff What do you mean has no table `product_sizes`? Sure it does. As a SELECT query works perfectly. What I need is to apply the same select method to single out only certain products so I can then update the formula for them.

Comment: @Borsn There is no details of  "products" table given.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this update with LEFT JOIN and Where

```
update product_pricing 
LEFT JOIN products_ids ON product_pricing.id = products_ids.id
LEFT JOIN product_attributes ON products_ids.link_id = product_attributes.fty_id
LEFT JOIN product_sizes ON product_attributes.size_id = product_sizes.size_id
SET product_pricing.formula_id= '2'
WHERE

product_sizes.wheel = '13'
```

Comment: Did you try the select if it return  rows

Comment: it could the problem is not on update , it could there is no entries to update

Answer (score 2):

I think an `INNER JOIN` is needed here:

```
update product_pricing 
INNER JOIN products_ids ON product_pricing.id = products_ids.id
INNER JOIN product_attributes ON products_ids.link_id = product_attributes.fty_id
INNER JOIN product_sizes ON product_attributes.size_id = product_sizes.size_id
SET product_pricing.formula_id= '2'
WHERE product_sizes.wheel = '13'
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
update product_pricing p
LEFT JOIN products_ids pi ON p.id = pi.id
LEFT JOIN product_attributes pa ON pi.link_id = pa.fty_id
LEFT JOIN product_sizes ps ON pa.size_id = ps.size_id
SET p.formula_id= '2'
WHERE
ps.wheel = '13'
```